# Left and Right ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android

I'm using Navigation Drawer and ActionBarDrawerToggle to implement an activity that has left & right sliding menu

here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/DrawerListLeft"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/DrawerListRight"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

There's only 1 toogle on the left, can I have another on the right?

here is the (only) toggle:

```
mLeftDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
{...}
```

Here is the setToggle fuction:

```
 private void setToggle() {

    mLeftDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Choose an item");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mLeftDrawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. i need sliding animation and im using support actionbar

Comment: @MikeM. im using default actbar pro!

Comment: @MikeM. I use an image for it: R.drawable.ic_drawer

Comment: yes, it slides left and right @MikeM.

Comment: @MikeM. i added my setToggle function above!

Comment: The v4 `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s sliding animation does not work with a standard support `ActionBar`. You need to provide more information about your setup.